# First line is not imported into DataTable from csv

Tags: c#, csv, datatable

I am working on a application which exports a csv to a DataTable and for some reasons, DataTable is not populated with first line in csv after headers row

I have tried the following code

```
Regex r = new Regex(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*(?![^\"]*\"))");

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName);
            string[] headers = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
            foreach (string header in headers)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(header);
            }

            line = sr.ReadLine();
            strArray = r.Split(line);         


            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                row = dt.NewRow();


                row.ItemArray = r.Split(line);
                dt.Rows.Add(row);
            }


            sr.Dispose();
```

csv file

```
FirstName,LastName,Address
Sally, Whittaker,Houston
Belinda, Jameson,Austin
Jeff, Smith,Seattle
```

Headers are exported just fine but the line after headers isn't uploaded as follows
[image]

**May I know if I am missing anything?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `ReadLine()` outside the while loop because its first read's the first line then in while loop reading happening after that first line.

```
line = sr.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an extra `ReadLine` you are reading a line below but not using it at the end.

```
            line = sr.ReadLine();
            strArray = r.Split(line);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove these two lines before your "while" loop:

```
       line = sr.ReadLine();
       strArray = r.Split(line);
```

Not only both are useless but the first is also the cause of your issue.

'Hope this helps.